# ROR + Refactor default line of scaffolding in Single Line of Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, redirect, refactoring, rendering

In Rails Controller, Using Scaffolding we generate default methods. Here One of the method is present. I wanna customized the last 4 lines into a single line. In my last project, I have done that today I am not able to memorize that single line of code.

```
  # Index
  def index
    @audits = Audit.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @audits }
    end
  end
```

Here I have to refactor the below code in single line.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @audits }
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use respond_with

```
respond_with @audits
```

and at the top of your controller define the formats you want with

```
respond_to :html, :json, :xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to { |format| format.html; format.xml { render :xml => @audits }; }
```